# Seperate Workload

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a huge amount of data(permutation of the characters a-z,0-9) that needs to be processed by a method(ReturnId). But this takes a long time, so I would like to split the input and feed into the same method multiple times.

I guess I should work with threads but I don´t know how the separate the input properly.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        List<string> combinations = new List<string>();
        List<int> Id = new List<int>();

        combinations = Permutations(characters, 3); //Method that creats all the permutations up to 3 characters

     foreach (var item in combinations)
        {
            Id.Add(ReturnId(item)); // Methode that takes the string and search based on that string on a website for an id.
        }
}
```

}

Comment: For permutations, a rather natural segmentation would be something like fixing the first character and then permuting the rest of the characters. The sub-tasks with fixed first character can easily be processed in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Parallel.ForEach` to schedule the work on multiple threads based on the environment system. The more processors on the system, the faster the parallel method runs. :

```
Parallel.ForEach(combinations, (item) =>
{
    Id.Add(ReturnId(item)); 
});
```

You can also use `ParallelOptions` to define the maximum degree of parallelism:

```
Parallel.ForEach(combinations, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, (item) =>
{
    Id.Add(ReturnId(item)); 
});
```

For more info, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Thank you, tried it out and it works way faster than before.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you want something like

```
public IEnumerable<string> Permutations(IEnumerable<string> characters ,int length,int current = 1)
{
    return current >= length 
         ? characters
         : from c in characters.AsParallel()
           from e in Permutations(characters, length, current+1)
           select c + e;
}
```

**note** this is not tested code and is provided as a guideline only

Comment: Sorry if I asked wrong, but the method where the permutations are made, works fine, only the method where I search for the id takes ages. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: the AsParallel() creates a  ParallelQuery which will use multiple threads to create the result set see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq?view=netframework-4.7.2